# How to set up a mock server with GoogleMock

Tags: c++, sockets, googletest, googlemock

I am converting old C code to C++, and I am testing it as I rewrite with GoogleTest. Part of my code uses sockets to connect to a remote host, with an IPV4 address. I am having a lot of trouble understanding how I can use GoogleTest and GoogleMock to test the socket part of my code.

My object takes in a host IP address and number of seconds to wait before trying to connect to a host again. There is a function called "conn()" that actually tries to connect to the host. That is the function I want to test. So in my test, I want to do something like:

```
TEST(CONNECTION_TEST, Connection) 
{
    MyObject obj("###.###.###.###", 1);
    ASSERT_TRUE(obj.conn());
}
```

I read on here that I needed to mock up a server since testing a remote host isn't really advisable. I am brand new to GoogleMock, so I read the official documentation and read the [GoogleTest primer](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md), [GoogleMock For Dummies](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md), the [GoogleMock Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md), and the [GoogleMock Cookbook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md). I watched CodesBay's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLB2aDasVTg). I looked at several posts on SO, including [What is wrong with my attempts to mock a simple C++ method with googlemock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780747/what-is-wrong-with-my-attempts-to-mock-a-simple-c-method-with-googlemock), [Patterns for unit testing a C++ method that makes a standard library call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779618/patterns-for-unit-testing-a-c-method-that-makes-a-standard-library-call), and [How to unit test BSD sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753538/how-to-unit-test-bsd-sockets).

For my mock server, I did the following. I made a Socket class that wraps socket.h, and then I extended MockSocket from it. In my TEST, I set up the mock socket to accept connections, like so:

```
TEST(CONNECTION_TEST, Connection)
{

    // bind to local host?
    MyObject obj("0.0.0.0", 1);

    // create the host
    MockSocket mock_sock;
    MockSocket new_sock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock_sock, create()).Times(1);
    EXPECT_CALL(mock_sock, bind(_));
    EXPECT_CALL(mock_sock, listen());
    EXPECT_CALL(mock_sock, accept(_));
    mock_sock.create();
    mock_sock.bind(123);
    mock_sock.listen();
    mock_sock.accept(new_sock);

    ASSERT_TRUE(obj.conn());
}
```

As you can tell, I don't know what I am doing. My test results fail and I think it is because I just didn't do this correctly. Please, can someone guide me in the right direction? Is the mock server the correct way to test my object?

Comment: Testing connection requires network and running server. You can probably mock connection by representing it as some abstract interface when testing classes that depend on it, but testing connection itself must be done without mocking. I guess it won't be "unit testing" anymore, but that is just a buzzword.

Comment: @VTT can you explain what you mean when you say "mocking connection by representing it as an abstract interface"?

Comment: How does you object interact with the mock sockets you create? You seem to be simply creating them, then calling `obj.conn()` and then... magic?  Please reread the Primers, especially the [Using Mocks in Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md#using-mocks-in-tests) section and consider posting a [Complete, Minimal & Verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @CharonX I have read the primer. I thought I could make a socket that is bound to the loopback, and then use my object to talk to the mock socket if I give my object the loopback IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to test?

Do you want to test if the TCP/IP socket class (assuming there is one), can actually connect and communicate with some TCP/IP service? This is more an end-to-end test. You can use Google Test to do this, but you need a running TCP/IP service to communicate with. This is not where the Google mocking framework is for. This is similar to when you want to test a class that reads a file: you need to have a file that it can read and Google mocking framework will not help you here.

Do you want to test if some other class, that uses your TCP/IP socket class, works? Here you can use Google mocking framework to create a mock for your socket class. This mock will act as the socket class to your other class but will not do any TCP/IP communication. This way you can unit-test your other class.

Comment: Your first scenario is what I am trying to do. Thank you for clearing that up for me!